# Jquery mobile table column toggle not working

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-mobile

I have tried to  implement column toggle from jquery-mobile.js . I referred code from [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_tables_columntoggle). when i am integrating this to django, column toggle is not coming.

Code not was working when i serve jquery, jquery-mobile files locally. If i provide external link its working.
jQuery v3.3.1 , jquery.mobile-1.4.5

```
<html>    
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Project</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bfslite/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'bfslite/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'bfslite/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'bfslite/js/sorttable.js' %}"></script>

    <script src="{% static 'bfslite/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'bfslite/js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{% static 'bfslite/css/main.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{% static 'bfslite/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{% static 'bfslite/chosen/docsupport/style.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{% static 'bfslite/chosen/docsupport/prism.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{% static 'bfslite/chosen/chosen.css' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{% static 'bfslite/css/jquery-ui.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'bfslite/js/jquery-ui.js' %}"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid table-responsive">
        <table class="sortable table table-striped table-hover table-sm" data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle"
            id="my-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Project Code</th>
                    <th>Project Name</th>
                    <th>Date Created</th>
                    <th data-priority="1">Type</th>
                    <th data-priority="2">Internal Status</th>
                    <th data-priority="3">External Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for entry in entry %}
                <tr class="content">
                    <td>{{ entry.bfs_project_code }}</td>
                    <td>{{ entry.bfs_project_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ entry.bfs_project_created_date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ entry.bfs_project_type }}</td>
                    <td>{{ entry.bfs_project_internal_status }}</td>
                    <td>{{ entry.bfs_project_external_status }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Please suggest me if i missed anything to add.

Comment: when you are providing files locally then check if path is correct and files getting downloaded on browser properly. Do inspect element and check files under sources tab.

Comment: Thanks. I found jquery, jquery UI , jquery-mobile js versions are not compatible with each other.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that your local static files are not loading. Try below changes.

1. In your `settings.py` add `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` in `INSTALLED_APPS` and define static directory path as `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`. This `/static/` directory is inside the django app in my case and it contains all the required files.
2. In your html file, add below code.

```html
<head>
{% load static %}
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="{% static 'bfslite/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'bfslite/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'bfslite/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js' %}"></script>
</head>
```

Hope this helps.